# Detect which FormControl in FormArray validator caused value change

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I can easy validate does array satisfy some validation rules at all. Problems became when I want to interact with specific controls within form array.

I have form array which contains form groups. Every form group has couple form controls.

Group looks like this:

```
const rowGroup = new FormGroup({
    'range': new FormControl(row.range, [Validators.required, CustomValidators.range([1, 10000])]),
    'multifamily': new FormControl(row.multifamily, [Validators.required, Validators.min(0), CustomValidators.range([0, 10000])]),
    'office': new FormControl(row.office, [Validators.required, Validators.min(0), CustomValidators.range([0, 10000])]),
    'retail': new FormControl(row.retail, [Validators.required, Validators.min(0), CustomValidators.range([0, 10000])]),
    'other': new FormControl(row.other, [Validators.required, Validators.min(0), CustomValidators.range([0, 10000])])
});
```

Form array contains groups and `ascendingValidation` function which does validation. Groups are added dynamically and they are unlimited.

```
const array = new FormArray([rowGroup], ascendingValidation);
```

In page result will be grid:
[image]

Form need to performs ascending order validation on 'Top of LTV Range (%)' column.

Example (I am talking about 'Top of LTV Range (%)' column always):

1. First case: If user change value in first row to be 44 instead 41 than this field (form control) will be invalid because user breaks ascending order. I would like to display error message only in first row because user changed that value.
2. Second case: If user change second row and add 40 instead 43 than that field need to be invalid. I would like to display only on second row field error message.
3. Third case: If user user add 45 in first row instead 41 than error message need to be displayed on that field. If user add 46 in second row instead 43 than error need to be removed on first row because ascending order is satisfied.

**PROBLEM:**

I am using form array level validation. **My problem is not how to implement algorithm to check is array ascending and which values are not in ascending order. This is easiest part**.

Within form array validation I can access to all array elements when values changes happened. Actually I don't know which control is latest changed.

**How to detect which control caused value changes in form array validator?**

**Is there any better way to do this kind of validation?**

Comment: It might be helpful for others if you split this question apart into two separate questions (a bit broad right now) and included relevant code including html on what you've tried and hasn't worked.

Comment: Have the grid an editor template? The grid provide a index scoped variable or Can you use the index of ngFor directive?

Comment: @LeonardoNeninger Grid is genereated with `ngFor`. Question is how I can detect control which emit value change?

Comment: @Z.Bagley Thanks. Do you have recommendation how I can split? In general my question is how to detect which control emit value changes in form array validator and is this right way to do this?

Comment: I would put pretty much everything that says anything about the grid in a different question (and maybe delete and re-ask this one if the answer below does not solve the problem). Also, for your `input`s you could add a `(change)="checkChange($event)"` which will give you the `$event.target` and to detect individual changes. Using `ViewChild` is another option to detect changes, but the general idea stays the same. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is another approach that can help you...
I use ngx-datatable which provide an complete api for column templating. The logic below track the last changed control name and row index.

My table definition is

```
<ngx-datatable id="tblMain" #tblMain formGroupName="details" class="material" *ngIf="!hideTable"
                       [rows]="items"
                       [headerHeight]="50"
                       [footerHeight]="50"
                       [rowHeight]="'auto'"
                       [columnMode]="'force'"
                       [trackByProp]="'id'"
                       [rowClass]="getRowClass"
                       >
```

**Note the formGroupName="details" which is a nested FormArray**

My column template is this.

```
<ng-template let-row="row" let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-value="value" ngx-datatable-cell-template>...</ng-template>
```

Inside the template I can control with part I show view or edit part..

```
<!--View-->
<div *ngIf="row != currentEditingDetail">...</div>

<!--Edit-->
<div *ngIf="row == currentEditingDetail" [formGroupName]="rowIndex">...</div>
```

**Note the form group name, the index of the row been editing**

Inside the editing part I show an input element which has a keydown event

```
<input type="hidden" formControlName="productValue"  [(ngModel)]="row.productId" (keydown)="processInputKeyDown($event, rowIndex, 'product')"/>
```

**Note: You can use the processInputKeyDown to track the last changed element.**

```
  Component({})
  export class ComponentComponent
{
  ...
  processInputKeyDown = (event, index, control) =>{this.lastGroup = i; this.lastControl = control}
  ...
}
```

I hope this can help you.